# Problemas ao checar empty()

Tags: php, string, empty

Estou tendo problemas ao checar uma string usando EMPTY(), é o seguinte.. Se eu jogar espaço nela " " ela deixa de ser vazia.. e acaba inserindo na database o valor vazio, como posso resolver isso, qual função?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remova os espaços em volta do valor antes de aplicar o `empty`:

```
$valor = "   ";
$valor = trim($valor);
if(empty($valor)) {
    echo "Sim, está vazio";
}
```

<sup>https://ideone.com/Afl1nm</sup>

A [função `trim`](http://php.net/trim) remove os seguintes caracteres, considerados "em branco", das duas pontas da string:

- " " (ASCII 32 (0x20)), um espaço normal.
- "\t" (ASCII 9 (0x09)), uma tabulação.
- "\n" (ASCII 10 (0x0A)), uma linha nova (line feed).
- "\r" (ASCII 13 (0x0D)), um retono de carro.
- "\0" (ASCII 0 (0x00)), o byte NULL.
- "\x0B" (ASCII 11 (0x0B)), uma tabulação vertical.

Comment: Nao sabia a existencia dessa funcao, me ajudou bastante.. Obrigado!

Comment: Que bom que ajudou. Atenção ao último esclarecimento que coloquei agora: a função `trim` afeta somente as extremidades das strings, espaços no meio não são removidos.

Comment: Mas pense comigo, se houver espaço no meio quer dizer que a string nao esta mais vazia, ou seja as funções cumpriram com seus deveres de verificação, correto?

Comment: Sim @user3163662. É que o papel da função `trim` não é deixar vazia, é limpar as pontas.

Comment: Mas,existe alguma forma mesmo fazendo essas verificações de o usuario burlar isso e preencher vazio?

Comment: @user3163662 Sim, existem certos caracteres unicode que essa função não trata.